# Editing File system in Visual Studio 2010Installer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-installer

I am trying to add a shortcut to the exectuable in the user's start menu.
There are many answer on StackOverflow that detail how to do this.

However, the all say something along the lines of 'Right click in the right-hand pane to...'

So I understand you all have an interface that looks something like:

[image: Right-hand pane for editing filesystem]

I don't have the panel on the extredme right - entitled 'Name' containing the Primary Output.
I have gone through every menu option I can find to enable this pane, but can't find it.

Anyone know how to show this window?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the Window Menu --> Reset Window Layout to see if that fixes your problem. It will reset the layout to default.

Comment: Also by right hand panel, are you talking the panel that says `File System` or the panel to the right of that one that contains the Primary Output

Comment: @Mark, Yep. Tried the Reset Windows Layout. No go.  
The subpanel with Name and Primary output is what I'm missing..

Comment: I am wondering wether the splitter has been drug all of the way to the right. try collapsing all of your side menus like the solution / property / toolbox etc to make sure that the File System editor is filling the entire window then look if you can see a splitter to the right. I have not found any way to delete that panel yet. You can also try right clicking on the File system Tab and tell it to float then make it go full screen to see if the splitter is visible then

Comment: @Mark - turn that last comment into an answer, my man. I floated it, killed all other toolbars, put it back, and it was just barely visible - hidden behind the other, by the looks. Thanks!

Comment: Done, You are welcome. glad to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am wondering wether or not the splitter has been dragged all of the way to the right. Try collapsing all of your side menus like the solution / property / toolbox etc.. to make sure that the File System editor is filling the entire window then look if you can see a splitter to the right. I have not found any way to delete that panel yet. You can also try right clicking on the File system Tab and tell it to float then make it go full screen to see if the splitter is visible then.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, tried to find another splitter but couldn't, got the 2nd detail pane by opening Visual Studio 2010 using the 'Run as administrator' command.